# Does my java code runs on multiple threads even if I doesn't use multi threading

Tags: java, multithreading, operating-system

I have a question about multi threading on the **OS level.**
I have a java code that does not use multi threading,

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int sum1=0, sum2=0;
    for(int i=0; i < 10000; i++)
        sum1 += i;
    for(int j=0; j < 20000; j++)
        sum2 += j;
    System.out.print(sum1);
    System.out.print(sum2);
}
```

As you see in the above code the two for loops can execute concurrently at the same time without making any mistake in the output.
Therefore, The OS can run my code with 2 threads simultaneously to speed up.
Does any OS use threads to speed up my code?

Comment: You're asking whether the **OS** would be able to analyse your **Java code** (or byte-code) and automatically infer parallelisation opportunities?

Comment: `two for loops can execute concurrently at the same time` False. They are linearly executed. First one loop (`i` variable) then second (`j` variable).

Comment: these codes never run simultaneously , the speed of processing is too fast so you think they are simultaneously , programs run line by line in java,

Comment: @UDKOX - The OP is saying that they *could* be executed concurrently without affecting observable behaviour.

Comment: There are a few (non-standard) programming languages with 'implicit concurrency'. Java is not one of them.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth True. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand your question, you are correct when saying the two for loops CAN run in parallel without effecting each other. However this is something you must do yourself in java. Here is an example for two threads running in parallel:

```
public staic void main(String args[]){
  Thread thread1 = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
      for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
       System.out.println(i);
      }
    }
  }
  Thread thread2 = new Thread(){
     public void run(){
      for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        System.out.println(i);
      }
    }
  }
  thread1.start();
  thread2.start();
}
```

If you want the code to "wait" for all threads to finish, then you can use the `.join()` method, like this:

```
try{
  thread1.join();
  thread2.join();
}catch(InterruptedException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```